# domPDF not downloading in Chrome

Tags: php, dompdf

Generated domPDF can't be downloaded in Chrome. It works fine in other browsers but giving this error in Chrome:

```
Mixed Content: The site at 'https://xxx.io' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://xxx.io/pdf/?doc=auAjvjYi8yyOJIfPq3t4prhrYdWsDDxXIG85XiRyNGo' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.
```

And this is the code block where I stream the PDF:

```
$domPdf = new Dompdf([
'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
]);
$domPdf->loadHtml($pdfHTML);
$domPdf->setPaper('A4');
$domPdf->render();
ob_end_clean();
$domPdf->stream($documentName, [
    'compress' => true,
    'Attachment' => true,
]);
exit();
```

And also the link to the PDF download route:

```
<a href="https://xxx.io/pdf?doc=auAjvjYi8yyOJIfPq3t4prhrYdWsDDxXIG85XiRyNGo" onclick="downloadPDF()" class="mobile-hide no-ul "><span class="icon-pdf"></span></a>
```

Comment: Seeing that `isRemoteEnabled` is set to true, are you loading in non-https images in your HTML that produces the PDF?

Comment: I just checked the whole generated HTML with `str_contains($pdfHTML, 'http://')` and there is not a single one inside the HTML string.

Comment: Is the SSL certificate valid?

Comment: Yep, it is Amazon RSA 2048 M01

Comment: Does F12 tools show the blocked resource loads in the network tab?

Comment: It doesn't show. But there is an internal redirect that may cause this issue. The route that I'm generating the PDF is internally redirecting to the same URL but with `http://` There are no rules set for this on .htaccess which is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so stupid. Since I didn't specified exactly the route like `https://xxx.io/pdf/index.php?doc=auAjvjYi8yyOJIfPq3t4prhrYdWsDDxXIG85XiRyNGo` (Notice the `index.php` after `/pdf/`) Chrome was automatically making an internal 307 redirect request using `http` to the route and then decides it was not safe to operate...